# Configure shadow of an ElevatedButton in Futter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to configure the shadow of an ElevatedButton in flutter. Right now, by default it has a slight offset to the bottom. I want to center that. Also, i want to be more blur/spread of the shadow.

These seem simple tasks, but im struggling to find the solution for it. I increased the elevation of the elevated button, which as expected created the illusion of the button being more elevated, but i'm looking for some way to customize the shadow some more.

What i have:

```
ElevatedButton(
               onPressed: () {},
               child: Text("Button 2"),
               style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                 primary: Colors.white,
                 shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                 ),
                 elevation: 20,
                 minimumSize:
                     Size(120, 58), 
               ),
             ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first thing, flutter does not provide direct options to customize blur and spread for the shadow, but you can wrap the ElevatedButton with a Container and use a BoxDecoration with a BoxShadow

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5), // Shadow color with opacity
        spreadRadius: 5, // Spread value
        blurRadius: 10, // Blur value
        offset: Offset(0, 0), // Offset (horizontal, vertical)
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text("Button 2"),
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      primary: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
)
```

or you can use a custom shape border like this

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text("Button 2"),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0, // Set the initial elevation to 0
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
      side: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.grey, // Set the border color to match the shadow color
        width: 1.0, // Set the border width
      ),
    ),
    shadowColor: Colors.blue, // Set the shadow color
  ),
)
```